# Why repeat עקיבא נחמתנו?

Tags: rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, maseches-makos

On the last Amud of Maseches Makkos, the three Rabbis in the story are inspired by the words of Rabbi Akiva and proclaim  [Maccoth 24b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Makkoth&df=24b):

> בלשון הזה אמרו לו: עקיבא, ניחמתנו עקיבא, ניחמתנו.
>
> Said they to him: Akiba, you have comforted us! Akiba, you have
>   comforted us!

Why the repetition of the statement?

Comment: See ktsirat haomer, kidush Hachodesh, A value of official approval.

Comment: Maybe related to the prophecy of consolation "נחמו נחמו עמי", where the *midrash* explains the significance of two types of consolations. See [here](https://www.kby.org/hebrew/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=4589) for a Hebrew article on this subject.

Comment: For emphasis? [char]

Answer (score 1):

It is a way of expressing the emotive content / value of the statement. They felt it deeply and are inspired, as you said.

See for example the idea of [diacope](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/D/diacope.htm):

> Repetition of a word with one or more between, usually to express deep feeling.
>
> Examples
>
> As Shakespeare's Tempest opens a terrible storm frightens those aboard a ship, of which one proclaims 
>   "All lost! To prayers, to prayers! All lost!"

Comment: This answer is logical but perhaps not sufficient to explain this case. May be that additionnaly to the main idea witch you have demonstrated, there is a desire to make a ceremonial manifestation.